# Mysql datediff with single column per user

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have this table in my sql:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 2023-07-10 |
| 2 | user1 | 2023-06-25 |
| 3 | user2 | 2023-06-21 |
| 4 | user3 | 2023-06-27 |
| 5 | user3 | 2023-07-11 |
| 6 | user4 | 2023-07-14 |
| 7 | user2 | 2023-07-16 |
| 8 | user1 | 2023-07-17 |
| 9 | user4 | 2023-07-15 |
| 10 | user5 | 2023-03-06 |

I need to calculate the difference for every consecutive date but per user (something like this):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2023-06-25 | 2023-07-10 | 15 |
| user1 | 2023-06-10 | 2023-07-17 | 7 |
| user2 | 2023-06-21 | 2023-07-16 | 25 |
| user3 | 2023-06-27 | 2023-07-11 | 14 |

and so on. I already searched online but found only solutions without per user.

UPDATE:
I arrived at this query that is very good but the output have multiple times the same date as start which I don't want:

```
SELECT 
    p1.id AS id,
    p1.name AS user,
    p1.date AS date1,
    p2.date AS date2,
    DATEDIFF(p2.date, p1.date) AS date_difference
FROM prova p1
JOIN prova p2 ON p1.name = p2.name AND p2.date > p1.date
ORDER BY p1.name, p1.date;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa0faf69)

Comment: What should the expected result be for the given data example ? You need the datediff for the first and last value per user, what if there is no last date per user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
SELECT
    p1.id AS id,
    p1.name AS user,
    p1.date AS date1,
    p2.date AS date2,
    DATEDIFF(p2.date, p1.date) AS date_difference
FROM prova p1
JOIN prova p2 ON p1.name = p2.name AND p1.date < p2.date
LEFT JOIN prova p3 ON p1.name = p3.name AND p1.date < p3.date AND p3.date < p2.date
WHERE p3.id IS NULL
ORDER BY p1.name, p1.date
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/756369/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

use a querie like this

```
SELECT `name`, `date`, DATEDIFF( 
    (SELECT `date` FROM prova sub 
        WHERE sub.`name` = main.`name` AND sub.`date` > main.`date` ORDER BY sub.`date` LIMIT 1)
        ,`date`) as nxttime 
  FROM prova AS main 
  order by `name`, `date`;
```

sample

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa0faf69/34

Comment: I need it for every consecutive date, not only max and min.

Comment: @Alessandro - i have change my answer

Comment: You use LIMIT w/o ORDER BY. Your subquery returns indefinite row from all matched ones, so the query is not deterministic and may produce incorrect output. Add ORDER BY.

Comment: This query produce also a null datediff for every user.

Comment: @Alessandro - YES, it is only a sample. you can add a WHERE or HAVING to get your result. you wrote **(something like this)**